# Phonegap quickbox chating history not save in admin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I try to save chat history in Phonegap at quickbox but history not save.

**My code :**

```
function sendMesage(event) {
    var message, post, userJID, qbID = getIDFromChat();
    //  alert(qbID);
    if (!$('.chat:visible').is('#chat-room'))
        userJID = getJID(qbID);

    if (!switches.isComposing[qbID])
        sendComposing();

    if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
        post = $(this).val();
        if (trim(post)) {
            sendPaused();

            message = {
                message: post,
                name: chatUser.name,
                avatar: chatUser.avatar,

                fb: chatUser.fbID
            };
            message = Strophe.escapeNode(JSON.stringify(message));

            if (userJID) {
                params = {
                    to: userJID,
                    from: connection.jid,
                    type: 'chat',
                    save_to_history: 1,

                };
                alert($msg(params).c('body').t(message));
                connection.send($msg(params).c('body').t(message));
                //  alert("showmessage==>"+qbID+"chatUser===>"+ chatUser.name);
                showMessage(qbID,
                            post,
                            chatUser.name,
                            chatUser.avatar || 'images/avatar_default.jpg',
                            chatUser.fbID || '',
                            null,
                            null,
                            new Date().toISOString(),
                            $('.chat:visible'));
            }
            else
                connection.muc.groupchat(CHAT.roomJID, message);

            $(this).val('');
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
<message to='5293986-24575@chat.quickblox.com' from='5293930-24575@chat.quickblox.com/1220770403-quickblox-14318' type='chat' save_to_history='1' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <body>
        {\22message\22\3a\22hello\22,\22name\22\3a\22vishnu\22,\22avatar\22\3anull,\22fb\22\3anull}
    </body>
</message>
```